# getting undefined error in axios get

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

My API response looks like this

```
data: {
    id: 9,
    quantity: 2,
    address: "Test Address",
    total_price: 144.42,
    created_at: "August 07, 2018 04:02:46 AM",
    customer: {
        id: 3,
        name: "Prof. Laurel Lemke",
        email: "velma32@example.org",
        role_id: 3,
    },
    product: {
        id: 7,
        name: "Pellentesque semper",
        description: "raesent sit amet elementum purus.
        price: "72.21",
        cover_image: "7CPVS7yjqba9iJ7J.jpg",
    }

}
```

And I'm fetching it with axios in which it is trigger when a button is clicked

```
fetchOrder: function(id){
    let vm = this;
    axios.get('api/order/' + id)
    .then( response => {
        vm.order = response.data.data;
        vm.orderModal = true;
    })
    .catch( error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
},
```

The response is successful and I'm outputing the value with

```
<span>{{ order.address }}</span> //Test Address
```

However, when i tried

```
<span>{{order.customer.name}}</span>
```

I'm getting an error of

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

How can i fix this ? thanks

Comment: your `order.customer` didn't have `name` object, or your customer was empty or `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your code is executed but the API call is `Async` and so customer is not defined till the time API returns the response but the code is executed. You need to put a check to customer before accessing the value.

`order.address` worked because **order might be object and so order.address will be undefined** till the API response is fetched. However, for **order.customer.name, customer is undefined and so customer.name breaks**.

Put a check of `{{order.customer && order.customer.name}}` and it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
<span>{{order.customer && order.customer.name}}</span>
```